# dynamic programming algorithm for the minimum number of primes

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

Develop a dynamic programming algorithm that calculates the minimum number of different primes that sum to x. Assuming the dynamic programming calculates the minimum number of different primes amongst which the largest is p for each couple of x and p.

Can someone help me?  Thanks.

Comment: Well, do you know what are the base case? Do you see a recurrence relation?
BtW, if you are dealing with not very big numbers, why not to assume Goldbach's conjecture?

Comment: @ Phicar  I don't have idea how to write the recurrence relation. That is what I need too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you name $f(n)$ your function, consider this:
$
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $n$ is a prime}\\
min_{1\leq k<n}\{f(n-k)+f(k)\} &\text{otherwise }
\end{cases}
$
**Edit:**

$
f(n,p)=
\begin{cases}
\infty &\text{if $p>n$}\\
1 &\text{if $p=n$}\\
\min _{q<p, q \text{ prime}} f(n-p,q) &\text{otherwise }
\end{cases}
$

Comment: you mean, you want every prime different, or as special case? like 20 =17+3???

Comment: 0k, i edit it. If you meant that, please edit your question because is not clear

Comment: I edited it. Thank you very much.